# Kubernetes service running on localhost

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed pods running nginx using helm, but when I do minikube service service_name, I see my service running on localhost as shown below.
[image]

I thought that you need to access the service via the cluster IP not localhost?

I tried to access it using the cluster ip with the port of the service, but it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried to run it again after stopping docker, but it seems that docker is required to start the kubernetes cluster.

I'm following this [kubecon demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQX5nokoqrQ&t=1214s) , in the demo she can access it using the cluster ip just fine.

Comment: On MacOS incoming requests are expected on `localhost` and are then forwarded to the cluster IP address (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: In my opinion it is enaugh to start minikube with minikube start --vm=true

PS. Remember to delete your cluster first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the cluster was created using default docker driver.

Here's the thread that I found the solution, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600378/cant-access-minikube-service-using-nodeport-from-host-on-mac)

Just needed to start minikube cluster using virtualbox as the driver.

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved using [`minikube tunnel`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel) command executed in separate terminal. This creates a tunnel and adds route to ClusterIP range.